# Different site opens up for HTTP and HTTPS

Tags: amazon-web-services, http, ssl, https, hosting

I have two sites lets say -

1. https://www.123.com
2. https://www.987.com

Now when I try to open the first site with HTTPS like https://www.123.com then it opens perfectly.  But when I try to open that site with HTTP like http://www.123.com then it opens my second site which is https://www.987.com though the URL shows http://www.123.com.

I have checked the htaccess file and kept it blank for a period of time but the issue still remains. I guess that means there is no redirection. There is no domain forwarding from my domain provider as well.

The websites are hosted on AWS. I have recently added SSL to my first domain after that I am facing this problem.

Can any one suggest what is wrong? and what should I do? 
ALSO I am a layman in AWS platform.

Comment: please share your configuration files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard to tell without knowing which services are you using. But assuming that involves ELB, you can set it up to receive both HTTP and HTTPS, let it deal with the certificate, and you can just forward it to your instance por 80.

Comment: Can you suggest any tutorial of how to do that? I have not configured any load balancer after installing the SSL as I have very little knowledge about these.

Comment: AWS docs are pretty great on this
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/classic/elb-create-https-ssl-load-balancer.html

Comment: Or in case your load balance are the newer one, not the classic https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/create-https-listener.html